# Background-image и border-image у одного элемента

Tags: css3

При использовании одновременно свойств background-image и border-image возникает проблема, что фоновая картинка не залезает под рамку в IE. В chrome/ff/safari - всё нормально.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  background-image: url('http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/mediumsize/PIA17011_ip.jpg');
  border-width: 30px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 13px;
  border-image: url(http://www.norabrowndesign.com/css-experiments/images/border4.png) 13 repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/nglazov/pen/gbNGrN если что

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо добавить

```
border-color: transparent;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vtzrnL6t/3/ - есть лишние свойства
http://jsfiddle.net/vtzrnL6t/6/ - сокращённый вариант

Comment: Т.е. получается используется border-color по умолчанию равный background-color?

Comment: @НикитаГлазов Не знаю. Какая-то магия IE, как всегда. Просто перебирал все свойства, связанные с отображением границ. Потом закомментировал border-image и получил чёрную. Решил попробовать явно прописать прозрачную - сработало. По умолчанию для границ цвет совпалдает с цветом текста, но тут явно не этот вариант.